# Getting headers in python from csv file

Tags: python, csv, header

So i'm trying to get this list of dictionaries

**List of dictionaries**

```
[{
      'cast_id': 1, 
      'character': 'W', 
      'credit_id': '5', 
      'gender': 2, 
      'id': 31, 
      'name': 'To', 
      'order': 0, 
      'profile_path': 'pQ'
 }, 
 {
      'cast_id': 2, 
      'character': 'Bu', 
      'credit_id': '52', 
      'gender': 2, 
      'id': 12, 
      'name': 'Ti', 
      'order': 1, 
      'profile_path': 'uX'}]
```

into this dataframe structure:

**Pandas DataFrame**

```
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|----|------|-------|--------------|
| cast_id | character | credit_id | gender | id | name | order | profile_path |
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|----|------|-------|--------------|
| 1       | W         | 5         | 2      | 31 | To   | 0     | pQ           |  
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|----|------|-------|--------------|
| 2       | Bu        | 52        | 2      | 12 | Ti   | 1     | uX           |
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|----|------|-------|--------------|
```

in python and I don't know how do do this.

Comment: Do you mean pandas dataframe? What did you do so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module to convert the string list to a list object using `ast.literal_eval`.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
d = "[{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'W', 'credit_id': '5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'To', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': 'pQ'} , {'cast_id': 2, 'character': 'Bu', 'credit_id': '52', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12, 'name': 'Ti', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': 'uX'}]"
d = ast.literal_eval(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)     #Convert to a Dataframe.
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       cast_id character credit_id  gender  id name  order profile_path
0        1         W         5       2  31   To      0           pQ
1        2        Bu        52       2  12   Ti      1           uX
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my solution from what I understood.
You can use pandas [DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns', dtype=None)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

```
import pandas as pd 

def main():
    data = [{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'W', 'credit_id': '5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'To', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': 'pQ'} , {'cast_id': 2, 'character': 'Bu', 'credit_id': '52', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12, 'name': 'Ti', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': 'uX'}]
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
   cast_id character credit_id  gender  id name  order profile_path
0        1         W         5       2  31   To      0           pQ
1        2        Bu        52       2  12   Ti      1           uX
```